# Qt6 собрать aab файл с двумя архитектурами armeabi-v7a и arm64-v8a

Tags: android, qt6

Подскажите, как собрать один aab с двумя архитектурами на Qt6?

На 5-м Qt утилита qmake располагалась в каталоге android/bin/qmake и вызывалась один раз с параметром ANDROID_ABIS="armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a". Дальнейшая сборка проекта давала aab под две архитектуры.

Сейчас qmake для каждой архитектуры находится в отдельном каталоге:

- android_arm64_v8a/bin/qmake
- android_armv7/bin/qmake
  Используя их можно получить два отдельных aab файла - по одному на каждую архитектуру. Но для загрузки в GooglePlay этот вариант не подходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по документации, Qt6 умеет генерить только Single-ABI bundles

> For Qt versions that supports building a multi-abi bundle (i.e. Qt 5.14 and 5.15), uploading one .aab with all the supported architectures is enough. However, for Qt versions that don't have the multi-abi build support, publishing your app requires additional steps.

Тут же и описано как их правильно загружать в Google Play
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/android-publishing-to-googleplay.html

Comment: Делал по aab сборке на каждую архитектуру с разными android:versionCode. При загрузке в Гугл был или ворнинг или ошибка - что-то про перекрытие сборок. Видимо, или нужно что-то ещё доработать по инструкции или проигнорировать предупреждение. Спасибо!